# Play (local) audio files using URL.createObject

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to run an independent webapp on a wordpress-page. So I created the html, js, css in the root directory. Now I got a problem playing audio files on the page:

I'm trying to play base64 endocded audio files with an audio player like this.

```
var player = document.getElementById("audio_player");
var data = "data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAADSeWyXAU9nZ1MAAAAAAAAAAAAA0nl";
var binary = convertDataURIToBinary(data);

var blob = new Blob([binary], {
  type: 'audio/ogg'
});

var file = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
player.src = file;
player.play();
```

But even encoded to base64 I get the error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found."

Also is there a way doing this without base64? Cause it's getting really big with larger files. And saving and accessing them from local files is not allowed in chrome, etc.

Comment: Isn't it easier just to store the ogg file somewhere on your server, and then load it dynamically into the `player` element? Base64 is an inefficient encoding system.

Comment: @Terry How would I do that? I must confess that I'm pretty new to server side programming.

Comment: You upload the `.ogg` file to the server. Then, you simply set the `src` attribute of your audio player element to the URI of the file.

Comment: Okay.. I'm pretty confused that this works. Wouldn't there normally be an error like:
"not allowed to load local resource" or something like that?

Comment: When I said server, I don't mean your local server. But somewhere on the internet. It's unclear what you're trying to do here: why are you attempting to load a local resource?

Comment: @Terry I think I got a misunderstanding about what "local" means in this context.
I thought it's the same problem when the files are on the server in a separate folder and that cross-folder accessing is a problem too.

Comment: In this case, the audio file is so small that I don't think the efficiency is a concern.  It seems legitimate, like embedding tiny image sprites and icons.  Of course that's depending on what you're actually doing.  But converting to a blob is pointless here.  Just put that data url and jam it into the src attribute.  Also, are you sure you want to use only `ogg`?  ogg leaves out a few big browsers